Text Prompt with Supplemental Image
Are there any AI image or video generators that will allow me to suppliment a text prompt with an image?
For example, my prompt may describe a person or animal reading a specific book.  I have tried this and at best I get an image or video where the title I provided is written on the front of the book as they read. But it is not the correct cover for the book.
I would like to be able to provide the AI with an image of the book cover to use.
Does anyone know of any generative AIs that will allow supplementing and prompt with a specific image like this?
